# Set value for column in Generic Repository

Tags: c#, repository-pattern

I'm using the generic Repository and UnitOfWork pattern to work with database.

Now I have an Insert method as below:

```
public virtual void Insert(TEntity entity)
{
    //How to set up like this 
    entity.UpdatedDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonth(-1);

    entity.ObjectState = ObjectState.Added; 
    _dbSet.Attach(entity);
    _context.SyncObjectState(entity);
}
```

The entity is a class that represent for a table, something like this:

```
  public partial class AM_User
    {
        public int UserID { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> CreatedDate { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> UpdatedDate { get; set; }
    }
```

The entity has a column named `CreatedDate`. I just want one place to input CreatedDate's value? How could I use reflector to set up its value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it via reflection:

```
typeof(TEntity).GetProperty("UpdatedDate").SetValue(entity, DateTime.Now.AddMonth(-1));
```

Answer (score 1):

The safest way is to ensure all of your entity classes implement the same interface, for example:

```
public interface IEntity
{
    DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
}

public class MyEntity : IEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
}
```

And change your repository to have a constraint on the generic type:

```
public class Repository<TEntity> where T : IEntity
{
    //etc...
}
```

Now your insert function can be changed to:

```
public virtual void Insert(TEntity entity)
{
    entity.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
    //etc...
}
```

Comment: hi DavidG, thanks for your help. But my entity is a class that represent for a table and generated by PowerTool, I cannot create one more  Entity as your suggest. I updated the question for more clearly.
Please advice.

Comment: Actually because the generated class is partial, you can just add your own file to extend the class and add the interface to it.